# Getting error sys.wwv_dbms_sql timeout occurred while waiting to lock object while upgrade to apex 4.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

i am getting this error this afternoon while trying to upgrade to oracle apex 4.2 from 4.1.1 .

sys.wwv_dbms_sql timeout occurred while waiting to lock object , but the installation progress continue .

Does anyone experience this kind of error? is it OK for my apex system cause the installation script keep continue, even in a very very long time. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like i have to restart the oracle because something access this application while i am trying to upgrade this.